# Windows directory paths, cmake, and escape characters

Tags: cmake, cmakelists-options, cmake-language

So, I have bought a playdate recently and I am trying to set up a project template so that I can use the C api. My issue is that when I am trying to call the path to the C compiler, which I have an environment variable, it makes the directory separator a back slash resulting in some of the characters being read as escape characters when parsing. I have tried changing the format of the path but it seems cmake uses the verbatim format when it brings in the environment variable that I have made. How do I force cmake to use forward slashes?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ5Lx.png)

Comment: Please, add to the question post the **complete** error message in as **text**. Note, that Stack Overflow discourages using *images* which represent *textual* information: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors